# How to calculate mean with hieraechical index in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 1mi rows and hierarchical indexes (country, state, city, in this order) with price observations of a product for each row. How can I calculate de mean and standard deviation (std) for each country, state and city (keeping in mind I am avoinding loops as my df is big)?
For each level of mean and std, I want to save the values in new columns in this dataframe for future access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with the argument `levels` to group your data and then use `mean` and `std`. If you want to have your mean as new column in your existing dataframe, use `transform` which return a Series with the same index as your df :

```
grouped = df.groupby(level = ['Country','State', 'City'])
df['Mean'] = grouped['price_observation'].transform('mean')
df['Std'] = grouped['price_observation'].transform('std')
```

If you want to read more on grouping, you can read the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)